# problem installing phablet tools

Tags: 19.04

When I add phablet-team's PPA using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
```

I get:

```
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu disco Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                       
W: GPG error: https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu disco InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

what can I do??

Comment: That's a dead PPA, no update for ages. Possible duplicate of [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: PPA's are 3rd party (personal package archives), and it's up to you to ensure they are trustworthy, maintained etc.  I picked one in your list, it was last touched by a dev more than a year ago so is it a surprise it doesn't support 19.04?  You should be checking PPAs or 3rd party sources of software before adding them (for security reasons alone)